# Is there a better way to implement multiple @font-faces?

Tags: html, css, font-face

My code is,

```
@font-face { font-family: Affogato-Light;   src: url("fonts/Affogato-Light.woff2")   }
@font-face { font-family: Affogato-Regular; src: url("fonts/Affogato-Regular.woff2") }
@font-face { font-family: Affogato-Medium;  src: url("fonts/Affogato-Medium.woff2")  }
@font-face { font-family: Affogato-Bold;    src: url("fonts/Affogato-Bold.woff2")    }
@font-face { font-family: Affogato-Black;   src: url("fonts/Affogato-Black.woff2")   }
```

Is there a `@font-face` or `{ font-family }` short form for multiple subfonts, i.e. `Light`, `Regular`, etc.? Thanks!

Comment: If your question is about mapping the different weights/styles to a single font-family, see Mr_Green's answer. If your question is about loading all of them with a single @font-face, then no, not directly in CSS.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, there is.

It is known as `Style linking`. You can read more about it [here](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/02/setting-weights-and-styles-at-font-face-declaration/)

In your case, the code will turn like this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: Affogato;
  src: url("fonts/Affogato-Light.woff2");
  font-weight: 200;
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: Affogato;
  src: url("fonts/Affogato-Regular.woff2");
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: Affogato;
  src: url("fonts/Affogato-Medium.woff2");
  font-weight: 600;
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: Affogato;
  src: url("fonts/Affogato-Bold.woff2");
  font-weight: 800;
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: Affogato;
  src: url("fonts/Affogato-Black.woff2");
  font-weight: 900;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

and later you can use it by applying following classes to the elements:

```
.u200 {
    font-weight: 200;
    font-style: normal;
}

.u400 {
    font-weight: 200;
    font-style: normal;
}

.u600 {
    font-weight: 200;
    font-style: normal;
}

.u800 {
    font-weight: 200;
    font-style: normal;
}

.u900 {
    font-weight: 200;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

You will apply font only once to the `body`:

```
body {
    font-family: Affogato;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not possible in CSS.

But you can use Mixin function in SAAS.

https://gist.github.com/jonathantneal/d0460e5c2d5d7f9bc5e6

Comment: That was my suspicion. I wrote a custom JS function to as a preprocessor. Outputs identical code as suggested in OP